# Why doesn't this call to `poll` block correctly on a sysfs device attribute file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, blocking, polling

I have a simple **sysfs device attribute** which shows up under my **sysfs** directory, and on a call to `read` returns the value of a kernelspace variable. I want to call `poll` on this attribute to allow my userspace thread to block until the value shown by the attribute changes.

My problem is that `poll` doesn't seem to block on my attribute -- it keeps returning `POLLPRI` even though the value shown by the attribute does not change. In fact, I have no calls at all to `sysfs_notify` in the kernel module, yet the userspace call `poll` still does not block.

Perhaps I should be checking for a return value of something other than `POLLPRI` -- but [according to the documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sysfs/file.c#L408) in the **Linux** kernel, `sysfs_poll` should return `POLLERR|POLLPRI`:

```
/* ... When the content changes (assuming the
 * manager for the kobject supports notification), poll will
 * return POLLERR|POLLPRI ...
 */
```

Is there something I'm forgetting to do with `poll`?

---

1. The device attribute is located at: **/sys/class/vilhelm/foo/blah**.
2. I load a kernel module called **foo** which registers a device, and creates a class and this device attribute.
3. The userspace application called **bar** spawns a thread that calls `poll` on the device attribute, checking for `POLLPRI`.

   - If `poll` returns a positive number, `POLLPRI` has been returned.
   - Use `fopen` and `fscan` to read the value from the device attribute file.
   - If the value is `42`, print *FROM THREAD!!!*.

The problem is that the message is printed nonstop when I'm expecting the call to `poll` to block indefinitely. The problem must lie with `poll` (the other calls successfully acquire the correct value of `42` from the device attribute).

---

*userspace app* - **bar.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handle_val(unsigned val, FILE *fp);
void * start_val_service(void *arg);

int main(void){
        pthread_t val_serv;
        pthread_create(&val_serv, NULL, &start_val_service, NULL);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;

}

static void handle_val(unsigned val, FILE *fp){
        switch(val){
                case 42:
                {
                        printf("FROM THREAD!!!\n");
                        break;
                }

                default:
                        break;
        }
}


void * start_val_service(void *arg){
        struct pollfd fds;
        fds.fd = open("/sys/class/vilhelm/foo/blah", O_RDONLY);
        fds.events = POLLPRI;

        do{
                int ret = poll(&fds, 1, -1);
                if(ret > 0){
                        FILE *fp = fopen("/sys/class/vilhelm/foo/blah", "r");

                        unsigned val;
                        fscanf(fp, "%u", &val);
                        
                        handle_val(val, fp);

                        fclose(fp);
                }
        }while(1);

        close(fds.fd);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

*kernel module* - **foo.c**:

```c
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static dev_t foo_dev;
static struct class *vilhelm;

static unsigned myvar = 42;

static ssize_t unsigned_dev_attr_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf);

struct unsigned_device_attribute{
        struct device_attribute dev_attr;
        unsigned *ptr;
};

static struct unsigned_device_attribute unsigned_dev_attr_blah = {
        .dev_attr = __ATTR(blah, S_IRUGO, unsigned_dev_attr_show, NULL)
};

static int __init foo_init(void){
        int retval = 0;

        printk(KERN_INFO "HELLO FROM MODULE 1");
        
        if(alloc_chrdev_region(&foo_dev, 0, 1, "vilhelm") < 0){
                printk(KERN_ERR "foo: unable to register device");
                retval = -1;
                goto out_alloc_chrdev_region;
        }
        
        vilhelm = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "vilhelm");
        if(IS_ERR(vilhelm)){
                printk(KERN_ERR "foo: unable to create device class");
                retval = PTR_ERR(vilhelm);
                goto out_class_create;
        }
        
        struct device *foo_device = device_create(vilhelm, NULL, foo_dev, NULL, "foo");
        if(IS_ERR(foo_device)){
                printk(KERN_ERR "foo: unable to create device file");
                retval = PTR_ERR(foo_device);
                goto out_device_create;
        }

        unsigned_dev_attr_blah.ptr = &myvar;
        retval = device_create_file(foo_device, &unsigned_dev_attr_blah.dev_attr);
        if(retval){
                printk(KERN_ERR "foo: unable to create device attribute files");
                goto out_create_foo_dev_attr_files;
        }

        return 0;

        out_create_foo_dev_attr_files:
                device_destroy(vilhelm, foo_dev);
        out_device_create:
                class_destroy(vilhelm);
        out_class_create:
                unregister_chrdev_region(foo_dev, 1);
        out_alloc_chrdev_region:
                return retval;
}

static void __exit foo_exit(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "BYE FROM MODULE 1");

        device_destroy(vilhelm, foo_dev);
        class_destroy(vilhelm);
        unregister_chrdev_region(foo_dev, 1);
}

static ssize_t unsigned_dev_attr_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf){
        struct unsigned_device_attribute *tmp = container_of(attr, struct unsigned_device_attribute, dev_attr);

        unsigned value = *(tmp->ptr);

        return scnprintf(buf, PAGE_SIZE, "%u\n", value);
}

module_init(foo_init);
module_exit(foo_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

---

#### See also

> [Using the Linux sysfs_notify call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367623/using-the-linux-sysfs-notify-call)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To quote some more from the comment you quoted:

> Once poll/select indicates that the value has changed, you
>   need to close and re-open the file, or seek to 0 and read again.

But you do nothing with `fds.fd`.

Also, do a dummy `read()` before calling `poll()`;
any newly opened file is considered changed.

Comment: I added `close(fds.fd)` above the `fopen` line, and called `open` again after the `fclose` call, but no change. Using `lseek(fds.fd, 0, SEEK_SET)` yielded no results as well.

Comment: You must read the current value from the polled fd before calling `poll`.

Comment: The dummy read is what solved it. I created a `char` variable called `dummybuf` and inserted the following line immediately after `open`, and also after `fclose`: `read(fds.fd, &dummybuf, 1);`

Comment: Though I do have followup question: is it normal for `POLLPRI` to be returned when a file is opened (thus warranting the need for a dummy `read`)?

Comment: For `sysfs` files, it's normal. (`POLLIN` indicates that the file is readable, which is always true.)

Comment: Dummy read because newly-opened-is-considered-changed was also the (undocumented!) missing piece that I needed to poll the `cgroups.events` file.