# Use poll() with POLLIN for waiting changes in file

Tags: c, linux, kernel, sysfs

I have to cooperate with kernel driver and wait in C application when sysfs_notify(3) for specific attribute was called. I want to use poll() approach via file descriptor.

My implementation looks like:

```
...
    struct pollfd *fds = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd) * 1);

    fds[0].fd = open("/path/to/file", O_RDONLY);
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[0].revents = 0;
    if (fds[0].fd < 0) return -EXIT_FAILURE;

    //! Poll and Process Descriptors
    while (poll(fds, 1, -1) > 0) {
        if (fds[0].events & fds[0].revents) {
            fds[0].revents = 0;
            ret = read(fds[0].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        }
    }
...
```

As result I got infinite unstoppable poll() activation in fds.revents by POLLIN even if no action were made for destination file.

I have tried my simple text file instead of kernel sysfs attribute and also got infinite unsoppable poll() activation for POLLIN with no action on file.

Can someone help me with solution?
Thanks in advance, Anton!

Comment: Files are always readable. It's things that can block like sockets and pipes that aren't.

Comment: If you want to monitor a file for changes use `inotify`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you share me some ideas of how to capture sysfs_notify correctly on  application?

Comment: According to comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404357/2402272, `POLLIN` is the wrong event to wait for.  You should instead wait for `POLLPRI|POLLERR`.  That doesn't seem surprising to me, since sysfs files should always be ready for reading.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your reply, I have tried ```POLLPRI|POLLERR``` but I got both fds.revents once and that's all. What may produce POLLERR in my case?

Comment: @AntonKalistratov, I would expect that to be a function of the driver exposing the sysfs interface you are `poll`ing.

Comment: @Shawn `inotify` probably won't work for sysfs "files" as they're usually created from in-kernel state when read.  There's really nothing to update, although I suppose a particular driver might be able to do that in some way, but that depends on how `inotify` gets its notifications.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's my own kernel driver, I've called sysfs_notify(attribute that I have to read) from kernel drvier inside interrupt. I can read any attribute with no problem, but I need to capture sysfs_notify somehow

Comment: @AntonKalistratov, I don't have personal experience with this, but my expectation is that once `poll()` returns a `POLLPRI` or `POLLERR` event for a sysfs file, it will not return another one on the same file until the driver performs another `sysfs_notify()`.  `poll()` is the userspace counterpart to `sysfs_notify()`.  I'm not sure what else you need if it's not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: Well, I've solved my problem. I had my own kernel driver and issue with sysfs_notify was here. I2C kernel driver has it's own structure `struct i2c_driver` and sysfs group registration `sysfs_create_group(2)` runs from internal driver probe. So instead of using `sysfs_create_group(2)` during probe just initialize `struct i2c_driver` internal `struct device_driver driver` field `dev_groups` by you group and it's registered in sysfs automatically during internal probe and also I've paste `kobject_uevent_env(&chip->client->dev.kobj, KOBJ_CHANGE, envp);` before `sysfs_notify()` e.g. on my driver:

```
ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(sfh7771_attribute);
...
static struct i2c_driver sfh7771_driver = {
.driver  = {
    .name   = SFH7771_NAME,
    .of_match_table = sfh7771_of_match,
    .dev_groups = sfh7771_attribute_groups,
},
.probe    = sfh7771_probe,
.remove   = sfh7771_remove,
.id_table = sfh7771_id,
};
...
kobject_uevent_env(&chip->client->dev.kobj, KOBJ_CHANGE, envp);
sysfs_notify(&chip->client->dev.kobj, NULL, "your_attribute");
```

On my user space code I've used `poll(3)` but as events there are POLLPRI | POLLERR flags and don't forget to use lseek() for seek to the begin of file. The short sample below:

```
struct pollfd *fds = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd) * 1);

fds[0].fd = open("/path/to/file", O_RDONLY);
fds[0].events = POLLPRI | POLLERR;
fds[0].revents = 0;
if (fds[0].fd < 0) return -EXIT_FAILURE;

//! Poll and Process Descriptors
while (poll(fds, 1, -1) > 0) {
    if (fds[0].events & fds[0].revents) {
        fds[0].revents = 0;
        lseek(fds[0].fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        ret = read(fds[0].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
}
```